# Vulnerable Windows DLL Not updating

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 2022 VM in Azure that vulnerability scanning is flagging because of an outdated Windows system DLL that has a vulnerability that was patched.

The dll in question is winmm.dll and the version in c:\windows\system32\ is 10.0.20348.1 which should be the original version of this DLL from the launch of Server 2022.

If I check the file manifest from KB5029250 (which is installed) it lists that this file was included and should be version 10.0.20348.1906.

I ran a `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and then a `sfc /scannow`. DISM does report image version 10.0.20348.1906 but SFC finds no problems with the DLL.

Out of desperation I even renamed the DLL and re-ran SFC only to have the DLL replaced with the 10.0.20348.1 version again.

Anyone seen this before or have any recommendations?

Comment: If you look at the file when was the compiled/modified, it should be August 3rd 2023. Can you provide a screenshot of Windows Update history showing KB5029250 was installed? Make sure you’re not installing only the SSU but both the LCU and SSU. Alternatively install KB5030216 which also updates that particular file with a 8-31-23 date

Comment: What’s the vulnerability number so I can do research